# Pythonic Substring Anagram Index

Tags: python, strings

I'm working on improving my Python skills and have been doing a daily code problem. For the problem:

*Given a word W and a string S, find all starting indices in S which are anagrams of W*

For example s = "abxaba" and w = "ab" should return [0, 3, 4],
s = "cbaebabacd", w = "abc" should return [0, 6]

Is there more efficient/pythonic solution than the code I wrote? Storing the queue as a list and casting it to set twice per loop feels like it must be inefficient.

```
def anagram_indices(w, s):

  w = set(list(w))

  queue = []
  index = []

  for x, i in enumerate(list(s)):
    queue.append(i)

    while(w.issubset(set(queue[1:]))):
      queue.pop(0)

    if w == set(queue):
      index.append(x-len(w)+1)

  return(index)

word = "ab"
string = "abxaba"

print(anagram_indices(word, string))
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, could you give us some examples of what your code is supposed to output for some inputs?

Comment: Question edited!

Comment: `print(anagram_indices("abab", "abxba"))`returns `[0, 3]`

Answer (score 3):

`index` is a singular noun that doesn't represent of group of things, therefor it isn't a good name for an array.

Your method is named `anagram_indices` and returns an array, I like to call the returned array `results`, so it's clear that the array are the anagram indices.

Using `i` and `x` is *very* confusing, so much that it made me question my own knowledge of the `enumerate` function. I expected `i` to be the index and `x` to be the letter, while it's the opposite. You should rename those with better variable names. Actually, using single letter variable names is almost never a good idea, there are some edge cases. I expect a variable named `i` to represent an index, for example.

Your algorithm itself is fine, but the naming is very confusing, which is kind of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

## `list`

A `str` is an iterable itself, so calling `list` on it in `w = set(list(w))`  and `for x, i in enumerate(list(s)):` is unnecessary.

## `set`

a set only has the unique elements. If the word `w` contains any double letters, they will be only counted once. A [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a more appropriate data structure

## `deque`

For the queue, a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (double ended queue) would be a better data structure then a list for additions on one end, and pops on the other. If you define the `maxlen`, you don't even need to explicitly pop.

## generators

You can forgo the `index` list, and instead `yield` the index at which there is an anagram

```
def anagram_indices2(w, s):
    len_w = len(w)
    if len_w > len(s):
        return # or raise an Exception
        # raise ValueError("`w` must not be at longer than `s`")

    word_counter = Counter(w)
    queue = deque(s[:len_w-1], maxlen=len_w)

    for i, char in enumerate(s[len_w-1:]):
        queue.append(char)
        if Counter(queue) == word_counter:
            yield i
```

The `s[:len_w-1]` is so you don't have to make a separate check for the first round of words

Which gives:

```
 list(anagram_indices2(word, string))
```

> ```
> [0, 3, 4]
> ```

```
 list(anagram_indices2("abab", "abxbabas"))
```

> ```
> [3]
> ```